# Blurring an Image in c pixel by pixel - special cases

Tags: c, image

I'm working on a program that will slightly blur an image in c.

Knowing that I need the average and rgb values of the 8 surrounding pixels and the selected pixel to change the color of that pixel, I've added them together and taken the average.

I know that the way I'm implementing this is not the most efficient way this can be done, so if there are any suggestions on how to simplify this, please let me know.

I plan on copy `tempimage` back to `image` in a third for-loop at the end.

The struct `RGBTRIPLE` contain the rgb values for a pixel.

```
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
```

My issue now is dealing with special cases, such as the edges of the image or the pixels on the side.

**How can I get the values of the surrounding pixels when the selected pixel is not surrounded by 9 pixels?**

Here is my code so far:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // copy all values to temporary image
    RGBTRIPLE tempimage[height][width];
    int avgRed = 0;
    int avgGreen = 0;
    int avgBlue = 0;
    //copy pixels to temp image
    for ( int x = 0; x < height; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
            tempimage[x][y] = image[x][y];
        }
    }
    //get average of surrounding pixels
    for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //TODO: edge check
            //surrounding pixels
            avgRed = round(((float)(image[i][j].rgbtRed
            + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
            + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
            + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
            + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed)) / 9);

            avgGreen = round(((float)(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
            + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
            + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
            + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
            + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen)) / 9);

            avgBlue = round(((float)(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
            + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
            + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
            + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
            + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue)) / 9);


            tempimage[i][j].rgbtRed = avgRed;
            tempimage[i][j].rgbtGreen = avgGreen;
            tempimage[i][j].rgbtBlue = avgBlue;

        }
    }

    //TODO: for loop to copy tempimage back to image here
    return;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antialiasing algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011274/antialiasing-algorithm)

Comment: you need to choose what to do when the pixels are not surrounded.  you could sample fewer pixels or you could re-sample the nearest pixel to the missing pixel

Comment: You don't need to copy the pixels to the temporary image. Read from the source and just assign them to the temporary as you go. For now, skip the hard part and just do everything but the borders. Use a loop and a lookup table of the offsets from the current pixel. Once you have that you can special case the edges and corners..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways of handling 'edge' cases in an algorithm like yours. The code below uses the current 'row' or 'column' (instead of that above/below or left/right of it) if it's on the relevant edge:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    // Edge check (A for 'above' index and B for 'below'):
    int A = i - 1; if (A < 0) A = 0;
    int B = i + 1; if (B > height - 1) B = height - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        // Edge check (L = 'left of', R = 'right of'):
        int L = j - 1; if (L < 0) L = 0;
        int R = j + 1; if (R > width - 1) R = width - 1;
        // Then change all your 'i-1'|'i+i'|'j-i'|j+1' indexes to A|B|L|R:
        avgRed = round(((float)(image[i][j].rgbtRed
        + image[i][L].rgbtRed + image[i][R].rgbtRed
        + image[A][j].rgbtRed + image[A][L].rgbtRed
        + image[A][R].rgbtRed + image[B][j].rgbtRed
        + image[B][L].rgbtRed + image[B][R].rgbtRed)) / 9);
        // ... and similarly for green and blue ...
```

Incidentally, I notice you have your pixel indexes as image[column][row] (= *column-major* order). Conventionally, `C` and `C++` 2D arrays are defined the other way round, as image[row][column] (= *row-major* order); however, as long as you're sure that's what you have, then no problem!

Comment: could you explain your code a bit to me? Shouldn't the if statements associated with all of `A | B | L | R` reset the `A | B | L | R` values instead of `i` and `j`?    I don't see how either i or j could go out of the set boundaries.    And also, in the end it is still calculating the averages of 9 pixels - I think the idea is to discard the out of bounds pixels and only calculate for 6 pixels (edge case) or 4 pixels (corner case)?

Comment: @DamjanOstrelic On your first point - well spotted (now edited to correct)! On your second point, the solution I offered is one option that does, indeed, always use 9 pixels (but always *valid* pixels); ignoring out-of-bounds pixels and reducing the divisor (to 6 or 4) is another (but *different) solution. Which is better depends on circumstance and user preference -  but 'your' method requires more code.

Comment: The 'always use 9 pixels' approach works on the assumption that the pixels beyond the edge would have the same colours as the corresponding edge pixel; that is, it effectively extends the image all round by one pixel, using the edges as the source colour.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I understand now. Using 9 pixels on the edge is probably the simplest way to do it - I'll try to think of something for the "discard" method. :)

Comment: @DamjanOstrelic Also note that, typically, the edges are: (a) only a *very* small portion of the entire image; and (b) more often than not, the actual "region of interest" in an image does not include the edges. With these in mind, you have to ask: "Is it worth the extra coding (and execution) time?"

Comment: That's a very good point. I think your solution is best of both worlds, but the assignment I have specifically requires implementation of the "discard" method so I'm going for that one.

Answer (score 0):

This code in C works well when you consider blurring an image or n*n matxix using box blur. It considers top, bottom and middle rows and calculates the pixels RGB respectively.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    int sumBlue;
    int sumGreen;
    int sumRed;
    //create a temporary table
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            sumBlue = 0;
            sumGreen = 0;
            sumRed = 0;
            //Top row
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (j == 0) //top row left corner
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4);

                }

                else if (j == width - 1) //top row right corner
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                }

                else //top row middle pixel
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

            }
            //Bottom row of image
            else if (i == height - 1)
            {
                if (j == 0) //left side pixel of bottom row
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                }

                else if (j == width - 1) //right side pixel of last row
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                }

                else //middle pixels of last row
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

            }

            else
            {
                if (j == 0) //left side of image
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6); //6 pixels surrounding the left side of the image
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

                //Right side of image
                else if (j == width - 1)
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

                else //middle pixels of middle rows
                {
                    //calculate for blue pixels
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 9);
                    //calculate for green pixels
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 9); // 9 pixels surrounding the middle one
                    //calculate for red pixels
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 9);
                }
            }

            //assign temp values with the calculated values
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((sumBlue));
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((sumGreen));
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round((sumRed));

        }
    }

    //copies values from temporary table and assigns to original image
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            //assiging temp value to original image
            image[j][i].rgbtBlue = temp[j][i].rgbtBlue;
            image[j][i].rgbtGreen = temp[j][i].rgbtGreen;
            image[j][i].rgbtRed = temp[j][i].rgbtRed;
        }
    }




}
```