# Blur filter in C results in only a slightly changed image

Tags: arrays, c, image, rgb

i am trying to make a blur filter in c that takes the neighboring pixels of the main pixel, takes the avarage of the rgb values and stores it in the temp array, them changes the image using the temp array values, it seems correct but it is not working as intended, giving an output of a very slightly blured image. I realy dont see my mistake and would be very thankful if someone helped, sorry if i made something horrible, started learning c last week.

i checked this post
[Blurring an Image in c pixel by pixel - special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296470/blurring-an-image-in-c-pixel-by-pixel-special-cases?rq=1)
but i did not see were i went wrong.

im working with this data struct

```
BYTE  rgbtBlue;
BYTE  rgbtGreen;
BYTE  rgbtRed;
```

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // ints to use later
    int j;
    int p;

    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for(int n = 0; n < height; n++) // loop to check every pixel
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        {
            int widx = 3;
            int hghtx = 3;
            // conditionals for border cases
            int y = 0;
            if(n == 0)
            {
            p = 0;
            hghtx = 2;
            }
            if(n == height - 1)
            {
            p = -1;
            hghtx = 2;
            }
            if(k == 0)
            {
            j = 0;
            widx = 2;
            }
            if(k == width - 1)
            {
            j = -1;
            widx = 2;
            }
            for(int u = 0; u < hghtx; u++) // matrix of pixels around the main pixel using the conditionals gathered before
                for(int i = 0; i < widx; i++)
                if(y == 1) // takes the average of color and stores it in the RGB temp
                {
                temp[n][k].rgbtGreen = temp[n][k].rgbtGreen + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtGreen / (hghtx * widx);
                temp[n][k].rgbtRed = temp[n][k].rgbtRed + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtRed / (hghtx * widx);
                temp[n][k].rgbtBlue = temp[n][k].rgbtBlue + image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtBlue / (hghtx * widx);
                }
                else // get first value of temp
                {
                temp[n][k].rgbtGreen = (image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtGreen) / (hghtx * widx);
                temp[n][k].rgbtRed = (image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtRed) / (hghtx * widx);
                temp[n][k].rgbtBlue = (image[n + p + u][k + j + i].rgbtBlue) / (hghtx * widx);
                y++;
                }
        }
    }
    // changes the original image to the blured one
    for(int n = 0; n < height; n++)
        for(int k = 0; k < width; k++)
        image[n][k] = temp[n][k];

}
```

Comment: Despite the **abysmal** code formatting, I can see you are reading from the `temp` destination image. Don't do that - all reads must be from the original image, and all writes to the temp image  (until you copy it back at the end). Looking through the code, the first pixel operation is reading from `temp[n][k].rgbtGreen` which has never been initialised anyway. And apart from that, you can't filter an image using pixels that have already been filtered.

Comment: You might find it easier to always loop from -1 to +1 and put the clipping inside the loop. Keep track of the number of pixels you add up and use that to average the colors.

Comment: Once `widx` or `hghtx` is set to 2 inside the loop, their values will not revert to 3 as you probably intend...

Comment: Inside the loop `for (int n = 0; n < height; n++)`, you have the condition `if (n == height)` — but that's never going to be true (`n` will always be smaller than `height`).  You have a similar problem with `k` and `width`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a combination of things.

1. If the code worked the way you expect, you would be still doing a blur of just 3x3 pixels and that can be hardly noticeable, especially on large images (I'm pretty sure it will be unnoticeable on an image 4000x3000 pixels)
2. There are some problems with the code.

- As @Fe2O3 says, at the end of the first line, widx will change to 2 and stay 2 for the rest of the image.
- you are reading from temp[][] without initializing it. I think that if you compile that in release mode (not debug), temp[][] will contain random data and not all zeros as you probably expect. (as @WeatherWane pointed out)
- The way you calculate the average of the pixels is weird. If you use a matrix 3x3 pixels, each pixel value shoud be divided by 9 in the final sum. But you divide the first pixel nine times by 2 (in effect doing /256), the second one eight times by 2 (so its pixel/128) etc. until the last one is divided by 2. So basically, it's mostly the value of the bottom right pixel.
- also, since your RGB values are just bytes, you may want to divide them first and only then add them, because otherwise, you'll get overflows with wild results.

Try using a debugger to see the values you are actually calculating. It can be quite an eye opener :)